# почему данная программа дает true и if выполняется?

Tags: javascript

`if(arr[i] == 1 || 2)` Где i != 1 или 2. Мне кажется, что если сравнить, скажем, 3 == 1 || 2 будет false, но, однако, оно дает true. 
Задача в том, чтобы сравнить элемент массива, и если элемент массива i != 1 или 2, то оно выводило бы некое сообщение

Comment: _3 == 1 || 2 будет false, но, однако, оно дает true_ - нет, не дает. Выведи результат

Comment: разве это не работает как if ((3 == 1) || (2)) ?

Comment: именно так это и работает

Comment: "нет, не дает. Выведи результат" - ваши слова. Далее ваши слова "именно так это и работает" (дает true)

Comment: @Степан Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе.

Comment: @Степан, выведи результат этого выражения, например в консоль, `console.log((3 == 1) || (2))` и посмотри что именно выведется.

Comment: _"именно так это и работает"_ - имелся ввиду порядок вычисления, который ты обозначил скобками.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это - `if(arr[i] == 1 || 2)` - не сравнивает `arr[i]` сначала с `1`, а потом с `2`, как Вы, вероятно, думаете.

Оно эквивалентно `if ((arr[i] == 1) || (2))`. Хоть `arr[i]` может быть равно или не равно единице, второй операнд логического `ИЛИ` - `2` - всегда является `true` в булевском смысле. Значит и все выражение будет `true` независимо от значения первого операнда.

---

```
if (arr[i] == 1 || arr[i] == 2)
```

```js
console.log(3 == 1 || 2);
console.log((3 == 1) || (2));

console.log(!!(3 == 1 || 2));
```