# Почему не берутся данные из формы

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="input_first_number" id="sum1">
        <input type="text" name="input_second_number" id="sum2">
        <input type="button" value="Применить" onclick="sum()"/>
    </form>
```

```
     let sum1 = document.getElementById("sum1").value;
     let sum2 = document.getElementById("sum2").value;
     function sum() {
         alert(+sum1 + +sum2);
 }
```

алерт выводит 0, я ожидал, что будет выводится сумма формы sum1 и формы sum2

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097489/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-true-%d0%b8-if-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что Вы получаете значения `sum1` и `sum2` во время загрузки страницы, когда инпуты пустые.

```
function sum() {
  let sum1 = document.getElementById("sum1").value;
  let sum2 = document.getElementById("sum2").value;
  alert(+sum1 + +sum2);
}
```

или

```
let sum1 = document.getElementById("sum1");
let sum2 = document.getElementById("sum2");
function sum() {
  alert(+sum1.value + +sum2.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй [JQ](https://jquery.com/download/)

```js
$('input[type="button"]').click(()=>{
    const sum1 = parseInt($('#sum1').val());
    const sum2 = parseInt($('#sum2').val());
    const fin = summ(sum1, sum2);
    console.log(fin);
    // либо без одноразовых пелеменных:
    console.log(summ($('#sum1').val(), $('#sum2').val()));
});

const summ=(a, b)=>(a+b);
```

Comment: И как, работает?

Comment: @Igor что конкретно?

Comment: сумма *(10 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor https://imgur.com/a/zDpCHtX а потестить?

Comment: Красивая картинка. `$().val()` возвращает строку.

Comment: @Igor я оставлю выбор за автором вопроса, использовать тип нумбер у полей, либо парсИнт, либо оставить так, ибо стак случился на шаге взятия данных, а не обработки строк в инт.

Comment: @Igor тем более, если учитывать то, что .value тоже.